# System.console() gives a NullPointerException in NetBeans

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, nullpointerexception, console

I have the following problem: method `readLine()` or `nextLine()`, `nextInt()`, etc. throw an exception: `NullPointerException`.

I use the [NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) IDE (if it matters).

```
public static void Reading()
{
    String qq;
    qq = System.console().readLine();
    System.console().printf(qq);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some IDEs don't provide a console. Note that `System.console()` returns `null` in these cases.

From [the documentanion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29)

> ***Returns:***
>
> *The system console, if any, otherwise null.*

You can always use `System.in` and `System.out` instead, as follows:

```
String qq;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
qq = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println(qq);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. The standard way of printing things is `System.out.println("Thing to print");`
2. The standard way of reading input off the console is: `Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); String input = s.nextLine();`

So with these in mind, your code should be

```
public static void Reading() {
    String qq;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    qq = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println(qq);
    s.close();
}
```

or

```
public static void Reading() {
    String qq;
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        qq = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println(qq);
    }
}
```