# Java console and GUI mode of application?

Tags: java, maven, user-interface, terminal

What is the best way to create application that can be used both as GUI app and console tool?

Here is relative info: [Can one executable be both a console and GUI application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493536/can-one-executable-be-both-a-console-and-gui-application)

My question is more about Java, Maven, JavaFX - my app currently runs as JavaFX GUI application.

P.S. Any relative help, very appreciated. I am totally confused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably do this:

1. Add an option like `java -jar MyApp.jar -gui`
2. Fall back to console if no GUI is available, e.g. Java runs in headless mode
3. Use the `Console` class for the console ui.

Comment: Is there any options to use builded with Maven javaFX .exe file with console? System.console() returns _null_ .
I need somehow attach console to a process.

Comment: `System.console() returns null`  may be due to run your code from IDE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078106/system-console-gives-nullpointerexception-in-netbeans